# SQL Query for order the record by using CASE statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table plant that 
 returns following results when i select the record as:-

```
SELECT PLANT_NAME FROM PLANT

Plant_Name
-----------
Chicago 65th
-----------
Clearfield
-----------
Lithonia
-----------
Los Angeles
-----------
North Bergen
-----------
Zellwood
-----------
Olathe
-----------
Archerfield
-----------
Epping
-----------
```

I write the following query to display the plant name "Zellwood" in second last and "Archerfield" in last row. The Query is

```
select Plant_Name from plant order by  case  Plant_Name

 when 'Zellwood' then 1
 when  'Archerfield' then 2
 end
```

but it doesn't order the rest of the records .Please give me suggestion how i can  order the rest of the record of table in Ascending order.

Answer (score 3):

Use a second key in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select Plant_Name
from plant
order by (case Plant_Name
             when 'Zellwood' then 1
             when 'Archerfield' then 2
          end),
         Plant_Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Query is,**

```
select ColumnName
    from Tablename
    order by (case Column Name when 'value' then 1 when 'value' then 2 end), Column Name);
```